# Javascript onunload function

Tags: javascript, meteor

I read a lot on this, but I still can't figure it out. 
I have to do some jobs when the user leaves my page. So I used the window.onbeforeunload to warn him that he will quit the page and the window.onunload to launch my job.
The problem is, when I'm doing the onunload function, it doesn't finish correctly before my page is already closed.

I tried this then :

```
        window.onunload = function() {

            //freezeScreen(5000);

            console.log("destroy finished 1/8");

            $.each(_tabClassObj, function(index) {
                _tabClassObj[index].destroy();
            });
            console.log("destroy finished 2/8");
            _tabClassObj = {};
            console.log("destroy finished 3/8");
            _terminalTabCounter = 0;
            console.log("destroy finished 4/8");
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            console.log("destroy finished 5/8");
            window.onunload = null;
            console.log("destroy finished 6/8");
        }
```

Here is my console log :

```
destroy finished 1/8
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.
```

I tried to delay the browser UI from closing with the freeze function that delays my browser shutdown by 5 sec... but it's still not working. I also tried a setTimeout here... but with the same result.
What is the problem ?
Thanks for advice.

Comment: Can you clarify why any of the actions you are taking on `unload` are relevant? I mean: clearing variables and such seems useless when that happens anyway when you unload the page.

Comment: put `return false` as the last line in `onunload` function.

Comment: You seem to be doing a whole lot of strange stuff that's not necessary, after your unload has already began. And you need to return true or false back to state whether it's been handled or not. If you don't wish to proceed with the unload, then return false from your handler above.

Comment: Thanks for your replys. This is an example. The fact is, i'm using meteor and with my iron:router, this is the a function who is called when i'm changing page. So I still put in this example the code who is really executed.

Comment: The return false solution doesn't work. My page still close instantly and still got my : WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't done what i would like with javascript event. 
To mention my meteor server my client has closed his browser, I developped a ping system like that :

```
// Both side
TelnetUserConnections = new Meteor.Collection('TelnetUserConnections');

// Client side
Meteor.startup(function(){
    // Timer who refresh the heartbeat on server
    Meteor.setInterval(function () {
        Meteor.call('keepAlive', Blaze._globalHelpers.currentUserId());
    }, 5000);
});

// Server side
Meteor.methods({
    "keepAlive": function (user_id) {
        if (!TelnetUserConnections.findOne({user_id: user_id})) {
           TelnetUserConnections.insert({user_id: user_id});
        }
        TelnetUserConnections.update({user_id: user_id}, {$set: {last_seen: (new Date()).getTime()}});
    }
});

Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    // do the job when user hasn't pinged since 20 secondes
    var now = (new Date()).getTime();
    TelnetUserConnections.find({last_seen: {$lt: (now - 20 * 1000)}}).forEach(function (user) {

        /* here is my destroy stuff */

        TelnetUserConnections.remove({_id : user._id});
    });
});
```

Maybe it can helps

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Blaze` as your view Layer, you have the access of `onDestroy` method to write the logic you want to put on before leaving the url.

```
Template.xxx.onDestroy( function() {
    // logic goes here.
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Faysal. I already tried to use blaze template event... but no one is normally triggered. The "onDestroy" like you mention return me a error message that is not a function. I tried the onDestroyed, but here it is not triggered... it's why I tried to passed directly by javascript event.